# Automatically hide certain shapes with Disappear-animation in exported PDF

Tags: windows, pdf, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

In my slides I have a few shapes covering other content. Those shapes have a "*Disappear*" animation on them and are supposed to hide information such that the audience can think about it first.

**Note**: It's not (or at least not easily) possible for me to let the relevant information "*Appear*" instead of hiding it.

When I export my slides as PDF, all those blocking-shapes are still in the PDF, although they have a "*Disappear*" animation. So far, I needed to manually delete all of those blocking-shapes, export as PDF and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> until all shapes are back.

Is there a better way to do it? For example by marking certain shapes to be hidden in the PDF?

Comment: With other programs it was possible to have 2 pages exporting to PDF: the first with the beginning of the animation (the shapes cover) and the second with the end of the animation (the shapes are hidden or better transparent). Check if it is ok for you and if you can do it with your office too. PS> [edit] your post adding the version of powerpoint you are using...

Comment: @Hastur I added my version: 2013. I haven't found such an option yet, but it would certainly be better than my current situation! So if you can tell me more about it, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: There are many add-ons to do it, but I cannot be sure there is not a way to do it  _"inside"_ powerpoint: give it a look to "[Create a PDF from PowerPoint with animations](http://superuser.com/q/602209/257269)" and  more to "[Export PowerPoint to PDF with each animation on a separate slide](http://superuser.com/questions/75550/export-powerpoint-to-pdf-with-each-animation-on-a-separate-slide)". Maybe it was inside LibreOffice (you can import your ppt with some conversion risk)... just directions, at present I don't remember more precisely...

Comment: A separate line. It is possible to _print to_ a pdf, installing a pdf printer (or drivers...). If you can specify (in the characteristics of your animation/object) that this animation has not to be printed you have solved your problem...

Answer (score 0):

I have a free add-in that might help:

Creating Teacher / Student editions of presentations
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ01017_Creating_Teacher_-_Student_editions_of_presentations.htm

Since it doesn't use animation (it makes shapes visible or invisible as needed instead), the results should export to PDF the way you expect them to.