# PowerPoint Builds or Bullet points saving as a PNG

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I know how to save as PNG.  When there is a build it only saves the final build of the slide.  I would like each bullet point as it builds as a png.  Any ideas?  Thanks,  James

Comment: I don't know if saving to png is possible, but you can save the animations to a PDF if that helps you. See [windows - Export PowerPoint to PDF with each animation on a separate slide - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/75550/export-powerpoint-to-pdf-with-each-animation-on-a-separate-slide)

Comment: Thanks.  Saving as PDF would not be useful.  Need as PNG to edit in a video.

Comment: So save it straight to video (including animations)?. See [Turn your presentation into a video - PowerPoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/turn-your-presentation-into-a-video-c140551f-cb37-4818-b5d4-3e30815c3e83)

Comment: Turns out the program for export PowerPoint to PDF worked great.  Just downloaded and used it. It is working. Description should be changed because you are creating a new PowerPoint that has more slides and can be converted to whatever you want including PDF and PNG.  The PDF in the title threw me off. Thanks again.  Problem solved!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply press the PrintScr button on the desired screen and open paint and press `ctr+v` to paste then crop content you want and save it as PNG.